# Modify an existing function and stopped by an error from parent.frame()

Tags: r

I am trying to copy and further modify an existing function in R::stats for personal customizable use. Below is the data.

```
library(survey)
> dput(y)
c(`167` = 2568.94, `168` = 4195.27, `169` = 21975.62, `170` = 1334.39, 
`172` = 1465.59, `173` = 14937.02, `179` = 3731.79, `181` = 1737.58, 
`182` = 1661.06, `186` = 2605.34, `187` = 2344.81, `188` = 5271.69, 
`189` = 3868.3, `190` = 5394.89, `191` = 5880.82, `193` = 2102.45, 
`195` = 14937.02, `197` = 2741.65, `198` = 13521.98, `201` = 15801.51
)
> dput(x)
c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
> dput(sample_data)
structure(list(ACP = c(1L, 4L, 81L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 18L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 5L), ACPSI = c(0.02, 0.07, 
1.51, 0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.06, 0.02, 0.11, 0.04, 0.34, 0.04, 
0.07, 0.02, 0.04, 0.07, 0.02, 0.28, 0.09), AHP = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), AMP = c(4.6, 4.5, 4.3, 4.6, 4.1, 5, 4.8, 4.5, 4.1, 4.2, 
5.1, 4.2, 4.9, 4.8, 3.6, 4.4, 4.9, 4.8, 3.9, 4.4), AMPSI = c(46L, 
45L, 43L, 46L, 41L, 50L, 48L, 45L, 41L, 42L, 51L, 42L, 49L, 48L, 
36L, 44L, 49L, 48L, 39L, 44L), APPSI = c(51L, 70L, 79L, 110L, 
101L, 67L, 151L, 87L, 105L, 87L, 51L, 86L, 98L, 72L, 43L, 45L, 
60L, 95L, 52L, 55L), BCP = c(10L, 14L, 130L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 6L, 
9L, 9L, 17L, 11L, 23L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 22L, 25L, 8L, 59L, 29L), 
    BCPSI = c(0.19, 0.26, 2.42, 0.15, 0.15, 0.3, 0.11, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.32, 0.2, 0.43, 0.09, 0.19, 0.07, 0.41, 0.47, 0.15, 
    1.1, 0.54), BUP = c(12L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 9L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 
    7L, 18L, 26L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 24L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 19L), 
    BUPSI = c(4.28, 5, 6.43, 5, 3.21, 4.64, 3.93, 4.64, 2.5, 
    6.43, 9.28, 3.93, 4.28, 3.21, 8.57, 5, 6.07, 5, 5, 6.78), 
    BXP = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 14L, 15L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 15L, 6L), BXPSI = c(0.09, 0.11, 
    0.14, 0.25, 0.27, 0.09, 0.14, 0.22, 0.14, 0.22, 0.16, 0.16, 
    0.16, 0.11, 0.07, 0.24, 0.18, 0.09, 0.27, 0.11), C1P = c(0.257, 
    0.756, 0.63, 1.032, 0.144, 0.529, 0.274, 0.751, 0.887, 0.14, 
    0.82, 0.203, 0.908, 0.189, 0.396, 0.46, 0.478, 0.212, 0.568, 
    0.676), C1PSI = c(0.257, 0.756, 0.63, 1.032, 0.144, 0.529, 
    0.274, 0.751, 0.887, 0.14, 0.82, 0.203, 0.908, 0.189, 0.396, 
    0.46, 0.478, 0.212, 0.568, 0.676), C3PSI = c(23L, 33L, 30L, 
    25L, 24L, 30L, 29L, 24L, 39L, 30L, 30L, 34L, 30L, 29L, 33L, 
    26L, 35L, 25L, 30L, 29L), CAPSI = c(2.31, 2.31, 2.25, 2.41, 
    2.27, 2.49, 2.23, 2.48, 2.37, 2.33, 2.39, 2.38, 2.5, 2.41, 
    2.11, 2.2, 2.4, 2.35, 2.18, 2.2), CEP = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 
    0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 
    1.3, 1.1, 1, 1.4, 1.1), CEPSI = c(106.1, 114.9, 106.1, 79.6, 
    88.4, 97.2, 97.2, 97.2, 106.1, 114.9, 97.2, 123.8, 97.2, 
    106.1, 123.8, 114.9, 97.2, 88.4, 123.8, 97.2), CHP = c(186L, 
    297L, 241L, 233L, 177L, 179L, 145L, 247L, 202L, 184L, 168L, 
    177L, 190L, 185L, 159L, 204L, 255L, 127L, 153L, 247L), CHPSI = c(4.81, 
    7.68, 6.232, 6.025, 4.577, 4.629, 3.75, 6.387, 5.224, 4.758, 
    4.344, 4.577, 4.913, 4.784, 4.112, 5.275, 6.594, 3.284, 3.957, 
    6.387), CLPSI = c(103.7, 110.4, 103.1, 107.1, 107.4, 104.7, 
    102.9, 107.5, 103.8, 107.8, 102.2, 98.5, 104.8, 105.5, 107.3, 
    106, 107.4, 106.4, 104.8, 100.5), CRP = c(0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
    0.21, 0.21, 1.43, 0.21, 0.21, 0.33, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
    2.2, 0.33, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 2.09), FEP = c(59L, 97L, 
    99L, 122L, 109L, 60L, 109L, 77L, 79L, 92L, 114L, 73L, 76L, 
    70L, 24L, 42L, 95L, 86L, 77L, 54L), FEPSI = c(10.57, 17.37, 
    17.73, 21.85, 19.52, 10.75, 19.52, 13.79, 14.15, 16.48, 20.42, 
    13.07, 13.61, 12.54, 4.3, 7.52, 17.01, 15.4, 13.79, 9.67), 
    FOP = c(2.4, 4, 6.4, 2.2, 3, 7.7, 4.1, 4, 3.5, 4.2, 4, 1.2, 
    3.3, 3.2, 6.6, 3.4, 6.5, 4, 8.6, 4.3), FOPSI = c(5.4, 9.1, 
    14.5, 5, 6.8, 17.4, 9.3, 9.1, 7.9, 9.5, 9.1, 2.7, 7.5, 7.3, 
    15, 7.7, 14.7, 9.1, 19.5, 9.7), FRP = c(31L, 329L, 121L, 
    89L, 24L, 206L, 86L, 191L, 199L, 55L, 125L, 23L, 138L, 270L, 
    42L, 80L, 119L, 127L, 125L, 119L), FRPSI = c(31L, 329L, 121L, 
    89L, 24L, 206L, 86L, 191L, 199L, 55L, 125L, 23L, 138L, 270L, 
    42L, 80L, 119L, 127L, 125L, 119L), HBP = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), HCP = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), HDP = c(51L, 47L, 42L, 
    33L, 61L, 37L, 41L, 33L, 38L, 52L, 27L, 53L, 30L, 33L, 51L, 
    55L, 51L, 45L, 51L, 47L), HDPSI = c(1.32, 1.22, 1.09, 0.85, 
    1.58, 0.96, 1.06, 0.85, 0.98, 1.34, 0.7, 1.37, 0.78, 0.85, 
    1.32, 1.42, 1.32, 1.16, 1.32, 1.22), I1P = c(4.04, 11.38, 
    9.31, 13.67, 5.43, 5.85, 5.26, 10.39, 14, 4.71, 8.65, 6.9, 
    16.68, 4.25, 5.49, 9.55, 5.09, 5.24, 12.26, 9.07), I1P2PFLG = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), I1PSI = c(24.24, 68.28, 55.86, 82.02, 32.58, 
    35.1, 31.56, 62.34, 84, 28.26, 51.9, 41.4, 100.08, 25.5, 
    32.94, 57.3, 30.54, 31.44, 73.56, 54.42), ICPSI = c(1.27, 
    1.27, 1.19, 1.31, 1.24, 1.27, 1.14, 1.29, 1.27, 1.25, 1.26, 
    1.25, 1.27, 1.25, 1.17, 1.21, 1.3, 1.26, 1.18, 1.14), LDPSI = c(100L, 
    105L, 145L, 158L, 146L, 166L, 130L, 181L, 163L, 152L, 103L, 
    123L, 220L, 224L, 141L, 134L, 155L, 144L, 169L, 144L), LUP = c(18L, 
    35L, 45L, 32L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 24L, 8L, 38L, 10L, 20L, 23L, 
    13L, 16L, 40L, 28L, 33L, 22L, 34L), LUPSI = c(0.32, 0.62, 
    0.79, 0.56, 0.26, 0.3, 0.25, 0.42, 0.14, 0.67, 0.18, 0.35, 
    0.4, 0.23, 0.28, 0.7, 0.49, 0.58, 0.39, 0.6), LYP = c(13L, 
    22L, 25L, 27L, 18L, 14L, 9L, 47L, 36L, 51L, 20L, 34L, 18L, 
    18L, 16L, 19L, 40L, 12L, 9L, 30L), LYPSI = c(0.24, 0.41, 
    0.47, 0.5, 0.34, 0.26, 0.17, 0.88, 0.67, 0.95, 0.37, 0.63, 
    0.34, 0.34, 0.3, 0.35, 0.75, 0.22, 0.17, 0.56), NAPSI = c(142.3, 
    142.6, 139.8, 143.7, 145.1, 144.7, 141.3, 144.9, 141.3, 143.6, 
    140.6, 137.5, 142.2, 144.8, 141.6, 141.1, 141.7, 142.3, 142.9, 
    138.7), PSP = c(4.3, 3.2, 3.7, 4.1, 2.9, 2.8, 3.5, 3.7, 2.8, 
    3.9, 3.6, 2, 4.2, 3.7, 3.6, 3.1, 3.4, 3.7, 3, 4.2), PSPSI = c(1.388, 
    1.033, 1.195, 1.324, 0.936, 0.904, 1.13, 1.195, 0.904, 1.259, 
    1.162, 0.646, 1.356, 1.195, 1.162, 1.001, 1.098, 1.195, 0.969, 
    1.356), PXP = c(22.3, 33.8, 26.5, 34.7, 25.8, 17.2, 27.7, 
    21.4, 22.3, 28, 25.9, 19, 21.2, 30.4, 7.4, 14.5, 26.5, 27, 
    29.2, 13.9), REP = c(3L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 
    4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L), REPSI = c(0.1, 
    0.24, 0.42, 0.1, 0.14, 0.17, 0.03, 0.28, 0.1, 0.14, 0.21, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.07, 0.07, 0.21, 0.24, 0.14, 0.21, 0.17), RUP = c(0.61, 
    8.19, 24.55, 11.24, 0, 0, 0, 10.7, 4.83, 2.34, 11.11, 13.17, 
    7.41, 10.81, 1.58, 2.61, 0.08, 12.64, 8.62, 11.56), RUPUNIT = c(6L, 
    87L, 281L, 210L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 188L, 53L, 22L, 184L, 157L, 
    106L, 175L, 14L, 32L, 2L, 253L, 123L, 149L), SCP = c(9.6, 
    9.7, 9.4, 9.7, 9.9, 10, 9.6, 10.4, 9.6, 9.2, 9.9, 9, 9.5, 
    10.2, 9, 9.4, 9.6, 9.2, 8.8, 9.2), SCPSI = c(2.4, 2.425, 
    2.35, 2.425, 2.475, 2.5, 2.4, 2.6, 2.4, 2.3, 2.475, 2.25, 
    2.375, 2.55, 2.25, 2.35, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.3), SEP = c(134L, 
    109L, 138L, 121L, 133L, 132L, 136L, 128L, 125L, 141L, 131L, 
    129L, 119L, 116L, 117L, 113L, 126L, 110L, 98L, 141L), SEPSI = c(1.7, 
    1.38, 1.75, 1.54, 1.69, 1.68, 1.73, 1.63, 1.59, 1.79, 1.66, 
    1.64, 1.51, 1.47, 1.49, 1.44, 1.6, 1.4, 1.24, 1.79), SGP = c(90L, 
    121L, 84L, 88L, 85L, 73L, 85L, 83L, 103L, 77L, 84L, 95L, 
    92L, 84L, 88L, 88L, 86L, 98L, 90L, 80L), SGPSI = c(5, 6.72, 
    4.66, 4.88, 4.72, 4.05, 4.72, 4.61, 5.72, 4.27, 4.66, 5.27, 
    5.11, 4.66, 4.88, 4.88, 4.77, 5.44, 5, 4.44), SKPSI = c(4.06, 
    4.24, 3.62, 4.78, 3.84, 3.97, 3.84, 3.93, 3.8, 3.73, 4.15, 
    3.64, 3.94, 4.7, 4.19, 4.13, 4.25, 4.07, 4.28, 3.55), T4P = c(7, 
    8.8, 8.3, 7.8, 8.1, 10.4, 13, 9, 9.1, 9.8, 10.6, 6.7, 9, 
    8.7, 4.5, 8.2, 8.8, 8.1, 5.4, 9), T4PSI = c(90.1, 113.3, 
    106.8, 100.4, 104.2, 133.8, 167.3, 115.8, 117.1, 126.1, 136.4, 
    86.2, 115.8, 112, 57.9, 105.5, 113.3, 104.2, 69.5, 115.8), 
    TAP = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 4.4, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7), TBP = c(0.6, 
    0.5, 1.1, 0.4, 1.2, 1.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 1.4, 0.3, 1.3, 
    0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5), TBPSI = c(10.26, 8.55, 
    18.81, 6.84, 20.52, 25.65, 13.68, 10.26, 8.55, 8.55, 23.94, 
    5.13, 22.23, 11.97, 6.84, 10.26, 10.26, 10.26, 5.13, 8.55
    ), TCP = c(166L, 299L, 240L, 228L, 174L, 180L, 142L, 246L, 
    195L, 183L, 167L, 179L, 183L, 182L, 155L, 234L, 248L, 123L, 
    154L, 238L), TCPSI = c(4.29, 7.73, 6.21, 5.9, 4.5, 4.65, 
    3.67, 6.36, 5.04, 4.73, 4.32, 4.63, 4.73, 4.71, 4.01, 6.05, 
    6.41, 3.18, 3.98, 6.15), TEP = c(1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.83, 0.5, 
    2.6, 1.68, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 1.38, 2.27, 0.07, 1.5, 2.95, 2.46, 
    0.77), TGP = c(47L, 109L, 231L, 152L, 88L, 274L, 153L, 130L, 
    110L, 93L, 154L, 99L, 256L, 109L, 80L, 162L, 80L, 103L, 65L, 
    139L), TGPSI = c(0.53, 1.23, 2.61, 1.72, 0.99, 3.09, 1.73, 
    1.47, 1.24, 1.05, 1.74, 1.12, 2.89, 1.23, 0.9, 1.83, 0.9, 
    1.16, 0.73, 1.57), THP = c(0.72, 1.2, 1.7, 1.2, 1.4, 0.75, 
    1.5, 1.4, 1.9, 1.7, 0.97, 1.4, 3.1, 2.7, 1.8, 2.5, 0.45, 
    1.9, 1.5, 0.99), THPSI = c(0.72, 1.2, 1.7, 1.2, 1.4, 0.75, 
    1.5, 1.4, 1.9, 1.7, 0.97, 1.4, 3.1, 2.7, 1.8, 2.5, 0.45, 
    1.9, 1.5, 0.99), TIP = c(265L, 287L, 374L, 352L, 422L, 348L, 
    394L, 359L, 355L, 328L, 441L, 384L, 358L, 230L, 325L, 289L, 
    358L, 318L, 264L, 389L), TIPSI = c(47.46, 51.4, 66.98, 63.04, 
    75.58, 62.33, 70.57, 64.3, 63.58, 58.74, 78.98, 68.77, 64.12, 
    41.19, 58.21, 51.76, 64.12, 56.95, 47.28, 69.67), TMP = c(0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3), TOP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 213L, 
    240L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 92L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 91L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L), TPP = c(7.2, 7.4, 7.2, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9, 7.6, 8, 
    7.8, 7.2, 7.9, 7.1, 7.6, 7.8, 6.2, 7.5, 7.7, 7.5, 6.9, 7.7
    ), TPPSI = c(72L, 74L, 72L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 76L, 80L, 78L, 
    72L, 79L, 71L, 76L, 78L, 62L, 75L, 77L, 75L, 69L, 77L), UAP = c(5.5, 
    7.2, 5.9, 5.3, 5.6, 7.9, 6.6, 5.7, 8.7, 6, 5.4, 4.5, 6.1, 
    4.7, 5.6, 6.7, 4.3, 3.9, 3.1, 6.3), UAPSI = c(327.1, 428.3, 
    350.9, 315.2, 333.1, 469.9, 392.6, 339, 517.5, 356.9, 321.2, 
    267.7, 362.8, 279.6, 333.1, 398.5, 255.8, 232, 184.4, 374.7
    ), VAP = c(43L, 61L, 67L, 56L, 45L, 71L, 65L, 60L, 47L, 50L, 
    65L, 54L, 54L, 34L, 75L, 51L, 65L, 59L, 44L, 73L), VAPSI = c(1.5, 
    2.13, 2.34, 1.95, 1.57, 2.48, 2.27, 2.09, 1.64, 1.75, 2.27, 
    1.89, 1.89, 1.19, 2.62, 1.78, 2.27, 2.06, 1.54, 2.55), VCP = c(0.32, 
    0.41, 0.32, 0.09, 0.95, 0.78, 0.59, 0.39, 0.23, 0.71, 1.16, 
    0.98, 0.52, 0.57, 0.17, 0.07, 0.73, 0.72, 1.5, 0.51), VCPSI = c(18.17, 
    23.28, 18.17, 5.11, 53.94, 44.29, 33.5, 22.14, 13.06, 40.31, 
    65.86, 55.64, 29.53, 32.36, 9.65, 3.97, 41.45, 40.88, 85.17, 
    28.96), VDP = c(19, 10.8, 27.2, 15, 52.4, 30.6, 32.4, 22.2, 
    32.2, 21.6, 24.2, 25.6, 29.4, 26.3, 13.7, 28.5, 48.7, 45, 
    24.5, 43.8), VDPSI = c(47.4, 27, 67.9, 37.4, 130.8, 76.4, 
    80.9, 55.4, 80.4, 53.9, 60.4, 63.9, 73.4, 65.6, 34.2, 71.1, 
    121.6, 112.3, 61.2, 109.3), VEP = c(738L, 977L, 1258L, 1201L, 
    959L, 1210L, 909L, 992L, 695L, 979L, 1020L, 861L, 911L, 804L, 
    794L, 944L, 1073L, 648L, 1022L, 1235L), VEPSI = c(17.14, 
    22.69, 29.21, 27.89, 22.27, 28.1, 21.11, 23.03, 16.14, 22.73, 
    23.68, 19.99, 21.15, 18.67, 18.44, 21.92, 24.92, 15.05, 23.73, 
    28.68), VRP = c(7.95, 1.62, 18.61, 14.94, 9.84, 15.97, 0.44, 
    8.53, 17.17, 6.93, 6.18, 3.48, 12.38, 10.93, 9.72, 16.17, 
    13.58, 13.51, 14.76, 16.41), D_CVD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), SDPSTRA6 = c(14L, 8L, 24L, 45L, 44L, 17L, 26L, 44L, 40L, 
    29L, 46L, 3L, 26L, 39L, 33L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 22L, 34L), SDPPSU6 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WTPFEX6 = c(2568.94, 4195.27, 21975.62, 
    1334.39, 1465.59, 14937.02, 3731.79, 1737.58, 1661.06, 2605.34, 
    2344.81, 5271.69, 3868.3, 5394.89, 5880.82, 2102.45, 14937.02, 
    2741.65, 13521.98, 15801.51)), row.names = c(167L, 168L, 
169L, 170L, 172L, 173L, 179L, 181L, 182L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
190L, 191L, 193L, 195L, 197L, 198L, 201L), class = "data.frame")
sample_design <- survey::svydesign(data = sample_data, strata = ~SDPSTRA6, id = ~SDPPSU6, nest = TRUE, weights = ~WTPFEX6)
```

The following function runs without issues.

```
> stats::xtabs(y ~ x, data = model.frame(sample_design))
x
        0         1 
125975.27   2102.45
```

When I look into the function code for `xtabs`:

```
> getAnywhere(xtabs)
A single object matching ‘xtabs’ was found
It was found in the following places
  (unknown)
  package:stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (formula = ~., data = parent.frame(), subset, sparse = FALSE, 
    na.action, addNA = FALSE, exclude = if (!addNA) c(NA, NaN), 
    drop.unused.levels = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(formula) && missing(data)) 
        stop("must supply either 'formula' or 'data'")
    if (!missing(formula)) {
        formula <- as.formula(formula)
        if (!inherits(formula, "formula")) 
            stop("'formula' missing or incorrect")
    }
    if (any(attr(terms(formula, data = data), "order") > 1)) 
        stop("interactions are not allowed")
    m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    if (is.matrix(eval(m$data, parent.frame()))) 
        m$data <- as.data.frame(data)
    m$... <- m$exclude <- m$drop.unused.levels <- m$sparse <- m$addNA <- NULL
    if (addNA && missing(na.action)) 
        m$na.action <- quote(na.pass)
    m[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
    mf <- eval(m, parent.frame())
    if (length(formula) == 2L) {
        by <- mf
        y <- NULL
    }
    else {
        i <- attr(attr(mf, "terms"), "response")
        by <- mf[-i]
        y <- mf[[i]]
    }
    has.exclude <- !missing(exclude)
    by <- lapply(by, function(u) {
        if (!is.factor(u)) 
            u <- factor(u, exclude = exclude)
        else if (has.exclude) 
            u <- factor(as.character(u), levels = setdiff(levels(u), 
                exclude), exclude = NULL)
        if (addNA) 
            u <- addNA(u, ifany = TRUE)
        u[, drop = drop.unused.levels]
    })
    naAct <- m$na.action %||% getOption("na.action", default = quote(na.omit))
    na.rm <- identical(naAct, quote(na.omit)) || identical(naAct, 
        na.omit) || identical(naAct, "na.omit")
    if (!sparse) {
        x <- if (is.null(y)) 
            table(by, dnn = names(by))
        else if (NCOL(y) == 1L) 
            tapply(y, by, sum, na.rm = na.rm, default = 0L)
        else {
            z <- lapply(as.data.frame(y), tapply, by, sum, na.rm = na.rm, 
                default = 0L)
            array(unlist(z), dim = c(dim(z[[1L]]), length(z)), 
                dimnames = c(dimnames(z[[1L]]), list(names(z))))
        }
        class(x) <- c("xtabs", "table")
        attr(x, "call") <- match.call()
        x
    }
    else {
        if (length(by) != 2L) 
            stop(gettextf("%s applies only to two-way tables", 
                "xtabs(*, sparse=TRUE)"), domain = NA)
        if (is.null(tryCatch(loadNamespace("Matrix"), error = function(e) NULL))) 
            stop(gettextf("%s needs package 'Matrix' correctly installed", 
                "xtabs(*, sparse=TRUE)"), domain = NA)
        if (length(i.ex <- unique(unlist(lapply(by, function(f) which(is.na(f))))))) {
            by <- lapply(by, `[`, -i.ex)
            if (!is.null(y)) 
                y <- y[-i.ex]
        }
        if (na.rm && !is.null(y) && any(isN <- is.na(y))) {
            ok <- !isN
            by <- lapply(by, `[`, ok)
            y <- y[ok]
        }
        rows <- by[[1L]]
        cols <- by[[2L]]
        dnms <- lapply(by, levels)
        x <- if (is.null(y)) 
            rep.int(1, length(rows))
        else as.double(y)
        methods::as(methods::new("dgTMatrix", x = x, Dimnames = dnms, 
            i = as.integer(rows) - 1L, j = as.integer(cols) - 
                1L, Dim = lengths(dnms, use.names = FALSE)), 
            "CsparseMatrix")
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x7fefabc170f8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Now I got the code and I tried the following:

```
> formula <- y ~ x
> data <- model.frame(sample_design)
> stats::xtabs(formula = formula, data = data)
x
        0         1 
125975.27   2102.45
```

No issues.

Then I start to run the code within the function `xtabs` line by line:

```
> sparse = FALSE;
> addNA = FALSE;
> exclude = if (!addNA) c(NA, NaN);
> drop.unused.levels = FALSE;
>   if (missing(formula) && missing(data)) 
+     stop("must supply either 'formula' or 'data'")
>   if (!missing(formula)) {
+     formula <- as.formula(formula)
+     if (!inherits(formula, "formula")) 
+       stop("'formula' missing or incorrect")
+   }
>   if (any(attr(terms(formula, data = data), "order") > 1)) 
+     stop("interactions are not allowed")
>   m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
>   if (is.matrix(eval(m$data, parent.frame()))) 
+     m$data <- as.data.frame(data)
>   m$... <- m$exclude <- m$drop.unused.levels <- m$sparse <- m$addNA <- NULL
>   if (addNA && missing(na.action)) 
+     m$na.action <- quote(na.pass)
>   m[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
>   mf <- eval(m, parent.frame())
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  argument is not a valid model
```

How can I fix the error about the `parent.frame()` within `eval`? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to know how a function behaves step by step, it is better to debug it, i.e. using `debugonce(stats::xtabs)` then run `stats::xtabs(formula = formula, data = data)` you will enter in  `browser` mode.

Comment: @user2554330 I still got the same thing.  ```mf <- eval(m, globalenv())
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :  argument is not a valid model ```

Comment: @RicVillalba When I ran with ```debugonce```, it will run without any issue. Because I need to copy the function code out and put them into my code, that is why I was running it line by line. What should I do if it runs fine with ```debugonce``` but does not work when running line by line? Thank you!

Comment: What `parent.frame()` do is to tell `eval` to evaluate `m` (here m is a "call" , that is, code like a function name with their arguments set but not called until `eval`, see output of `?call` for detail) as it was called from the caller environment. If the "call" arguments are variables they will be searched in the caller env, not in the xtabs function body. Thus, the best is to create a new function (i.e. `myfunction <- function(args...){..<code mod from xtabs>...}` and then run `debugonce(myfunction)` to debug your new function.